# SCCM PXE not working

Tags: pxe-boot, sccm, wds

How do I get the SCCM server to direct the clients so they get DHCP, and connect to the SCCM server?

Do I need to have the WDS role installed? Is this a requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short yes, "The Transport Server WDS role service is required for PXE support"

see: [Planning for PXE Initiated Operating System Deployments](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb680753.aspx)

Also I think it's pretty important that you install WDS then do nothing else related to WDS. SCCM configures it for you.

Comment: In our network we had to configure our DHCP server to return the `066 Boot Server Host Name` and `067 Bootfile Name` options as well.